# getting a list of files in a custom directory using glob()

Tags: python

Im trying to write a program that renames files when a use input their own custom file directory.
I'm at a very early part of it. And this is my first time using the OS and glob commands.
My code is below. However when I tried running that, the result was an empty list. I tried typing a file root directory into the glob command directly, it somehow works, but the result isn't what I wanted.

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks.

```
import os, glob
def fileDirectory():
    #Asks the user for a file root directory
    fileroot = raw_input("Please input the file root directory \n\n")
```

`#Returns a list with all the files inside the file root directory
filelist = glob.glob(fileroot)
print filelist`

fileDirectory()

Answer (score 2):

Python is white-space sensitive, so you need to make sure that everything you want inside the function is indented.

Stackoverflow has its own indentation requirements for code, which makes it hard to be sure what indentation your code originally had.

```
import os, glob
def fileDirectory():
    #Asks the user for a file root directory
    fileroot = raw_input("Please input the file root directory \n\n")

    #Returns a list with all the files inside the file root directory
    filelist = glob.glob(fileroot)
    print filelist
fileDirectory()
```

The next thing is that glob returns a the results of a glob - it doesn't list a directory, which appears to be what you're trying to do.

Either you want `os.listdir`, or `os.walk` or you actually should ask for a glob expression rather than a directory.

Finally raw_input might give you some extra whitespace that you'll have to strip off. Check what fileroot is.

You might want to split up your program, so that you can investigate each function separately.

Comment: Hi, but when i tried using list.dir i get a error which says, " WindowsError:[Error 123], the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:'"/*.*', is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the input you gave to glob actually "/*.*"? I think that may not be a valid path at all when running on Windows.

Comment: Sounds like you are actually using a glob - in which case your variable names and comments are misleading.

Comment: I would suggest trying the various pieces of functionality separately. In particular python glob module is unix-like expansions, so C:\* would get everything at the top level of C: (I think anyway).